# Nginx+apache+mod_fcgid настройка

Tags: apache, nginx, fastcgi

Как правильно настроить связку nginx+apache+mod_fcgid, что бы выдерживать dos атаки? Перекрыл весь гугл, но внятного ничего не нашёл, много перепробовал, но сервер как ложился от apache benchmark'a так и продолжает ложиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А Вы просто неправильно подошли к вопросу. Обычно в эту связку ещё добавляют фаервол, который делает подсчет запросов и блокирует, если они идут слишком часто. Классическое решение - [fail2ban](https://habrahabr.ru/post/236859/).

Следующий этам - это использование load balancer'a и нескольких серверов за ним. Тут можно начать с обычного [dns round robin](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS) или используют готовые решения, например, от [амазона](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/elasticloadbalancing/), который, если нужно и ноды дополнительные сам подымет.

Если и этого не хватает, то тогда уже используют аппаратные решения для отсечения зловредного траффика. Но это уже совсем другой уровень и врядли они Вам прям сейчас нужны.

Но если сервак находиться на слабенькой машине, а ддос идет с той же подсети (то есть, канал к серверу широкий), то никакой апач или nginx не выдержит, не говоря уже о php скриптах и средствами самого сервера сложно противодействовать.

Comment: Fail2ban стоит, машинка средняя по мощности. Проблема в том, что я понятия не имею как настроить fail2ban и за ссылку на хабр огромное вам спасибо)